# How to specify a certain amount of images queried, not all?

Tags: wp-query

I have a query for calling images from a post category. I am trying to control it to only query 6 images. I have tried using php count, but its not working as expected. Any ideas of what I could do differently to achieve this.

This was also the only way "I" was able to also include a "rel" tag for lightbox. Please keep that in mind if you know of a better way to do this.

Thanks -

I tried using the code pre tags and it wasnt showing full code so here is a pastebin link http://pastebin.com/kjkJQPR7

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'posts_per_page'=>6 variable to the array that you're passing to your get_posts query.

Comment: I am not really familiar with these wordpress functions. I have some things in that code that can probably be eliminated/changed. I added the variable to the array but it has mixed results due to query_posts above it which is displaying the category for the posts. And there is a posts_per_page variable in that too. So there is some confusion going on. But I cant get the $args array to show without the query_posts above with the category variable in it. I tried adding the category variable to $args but it didnt work....

Comment: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Don't confuse the issue further by messing with the query_posts. Just add `'posts_per_page' => 6` to the $args array. Nothing else to be done.

Comment: line 1. on pastebin has that already. your telling me to put it in the $args array - I did. It conflicts and does not give the correct number of images.

Comment: Here is the complete working code I have. I still think this could be cleaned up. - http://pastebin.com/TGvgAUyU

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding here. The first query_posts line is getting the posts, not the images. Then, you're looping through the posts and calling get_posts to get the images that are attached to each post. So the posts_per_page=6 needs to be passed into the get_posts call to get that number of images for each post. Are you trying to limit the number of images to 6 across ALL the posts you're looping through? Because then that would be different, and you'd need to change the code more substantially.

Comment: If you want to limit it to 6 across all posts, use code something like this: http://pastebin.com/Xgd3PJU1